# Are there vertical through-hole USB mini B plugs?

Tags: usb, connector, components

I can't find *any* manufacturers who make vertical through-hole USB mini-B plugs. I can find plenty of receptacles, and plenty of micro-B and A plugs, but no mini-B. Not even discontinued models.

Is there any particular reason they don't seem to exist?

Comment: My guess would be that mini-USB has more-or-less been completely superseded by micro-USB. I haven't seen mini-USB in any recently released device (3-5 years). I still have plenty of old devices that use it, though.

Comment: @Shamtam Plenty of new devices ship with mini-USB: calculators, radios, USB hubs, optical drives, and BeagleBoards, to name those I can see from where I'm sitting.

Comment: Hirose (HRS) UX20-MB-5P is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any particular reason they don't seem to exist?

Yes. Behold: USB Mini-A and Mini-B have been deprecated since 2007

http://www.usb.org/developers/Deprecation_Announcement_052507.pdf

> Dear USB Developer,
>
> With the recent introduction of the Micro-USB connectors, the USB-IF is taking the strong step to
> deprecate the Mini-A and Mini-AB connectors in order to minimize the number of cable combinations
> required to support the various product interconnections and minimize marketplace confusion. Based
> upon this, the USB-IF will no longer certify products that use the Mini-A and Mini-AB connectors nor
> products that use them. This change is effective immediately. Vendors of USB On-The-Go (OTG)
> products are directed to adopt the Micro-AB receptacle on all new OTG designs in lieu of the Mini-AB
> previously approved for this application. In addition, all Mini-A and Mini-AB connectors that are currently
> on the Integrators List will be removed.

Comment: Sure, but I can't find even any obsolete part numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need?

[Mini USB Type B Vertical 5 Contacts WR-COM](http://katalog.we-online.de/en/em/651_005_136_421)

Isolation resistance >1000 MΩ
Working voltage 30 V (AC)
Dielectric withstanding voltage 750 VAC/ min
Rated current   1 A
Contact resistance  20 mΩ max.

Its available from [Digikey](http://www.digikey.de/product-search/de?lang=de&site=de&KeyWords=651+005+136+421&x=0&y=0).

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for **plugs**. The male kind.

Comment: @Tortoise: I am not sure that there ever was a through hole version of the male connectors. You will probably only find something [like this](http://media.digikey.com/Photos/Hirose%20Elect%20Photos/UX40A-MB-5P.jpg).